# Flutter: Unable to remove custom plugin from being included in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I wrote a custom flutter plugin for windows which works fine so far.
For some reason though, flutter keeps including the plugin in the ios build when I'm trying to run it on the iphone simulator. This causes errors because the plugin doesn't have a ios implementation.
On Android everything works fine.

Here is the plugins pubspec.yaml:

```
name: fbfunctions
description: A new flutter plugin project.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.10.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      windows:
        pluginClass: FbfunctionsPlugin
```

And here is the error I get when trying to run on the ios simulator:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              2.5s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (`arm64`)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore_web/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_functions` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_functions/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_functions_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_functions_web/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `fbfunctions` from `.symlinks/plugins/fbfunctions/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `fbfunctions` in `.symlinks/plugins/fbfunctions/ios`

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:980:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:959:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:958:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:958:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:957:in `fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `10.1` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

How do I prevent flutter from trying to include the plugin in the ios build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; currently [Flutter expects every plugin to have an iOS podspec](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39659). Until that is resolved, the workaround is to include a dummy `ios/your_plugin_name.podspec`, as you can see in [federated flutter/plugins plugins](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_macos/ios).

You don't need anything in the folder other than the podspec, and once the issue is fixed you can remove it.